# How to split a string twice without an XML parser

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am trying to split a string twice

```
String example = response;
String [] array = example.split("<section>");
System.out.println(array[0]);

String [] array2 = example.split("<title>");
System.out.println(array2[2]);
```

I am trying to achieve this by using this code (not successfully), but instead of printing the first split i want to save it and carry on with the 2nd split. whould anyone have a solution to ths problem or better way of going about splitting a string twice? thanks

Comment: What is your input String?

Comment: Hint: `split` doesn't modify the input string.

Comment: `String[] onlyOneArray = example.split("(<section>)|(<title>)");`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to split first and then use it again, you may use the for loop:

```
  String example = response;
   String [] array = example.split("<section>");
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    example=array[i];
   String [] array2 = example.split("<title>");
   System.out.println(array2[2]);
    }
```

this will make you split the input once then split the results again.